# onBackPressed() can't make MainActivity to reload

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I am trying to reload my MainActivity after I do something in my SettingsActivity. My Up button in SettingsActivity works great and reloads MainActivity when returned from SettingsActivity. But back button saves the data but doesn't reload MainActivity when presses inside SettingsActivity. Basically my ***getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader()*** doesn't work with ***onBackPressed()*** Do you know, how can I fix it ?

My **MainActivity** is something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    }
}
```

And my **SettingsActivity** is something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){  //WORKS GREAT
        finishSetting();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {   //SAVES DATA BUT DOESN'T RELOAD MAINACTIVITY
    finishSetting();
    //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}

private void finishSetting(){
    if(newLanguageSelection==null || newLanguageSelection.equals(getLanguagePreference())){
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
    else {
        setLanguagePreference(newLanguageSelection);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Shows us your `onPause` and `onResume` of the MainActivity

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in `onActivityResult()` or logging something in there just to see that it's actually being called.

Comment: @Bonatti I don't have them. Should I ?

Comment: @Karakuri I actually have them in my original code. Data is actually saved. Just mainactvity doesn't get reloaded after backbutton as it does with up button

Comment: in your `SettingsActivity`, use a flag, then on `MainActivity.onResume`, check that flag, and if nedded, do your reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
[image: The activity lifecycle]

### Edit:

When you started the second activity, your Main is paused, and when the back button is pressed, it is resumed...

On your `SettingsActivity`, set a flag (such as using a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html))

```
SettingsActivity.onBackPressed(){
   finishSetting();
   SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
   prefs.edit().puBoolean("isShouldReload", true).apply();
}
```

Then, on `MainActivity.onResume`

```
onResume(){
   SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
   if(prefs.getBoolean("isShouldReload", false)){
      // Do your reload.
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please, tell me how to set a flag in my SettingsActivity, because, I haven't really used flags.

Comment: this link will help you to understand use of flags. [ https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/rZY3OSvYlms/p6tixh_eX1oJ ]

Comment: I solved it another way, but this gave me the idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Elnoor Good luck on your future endeavors, anyway, welcome to stackoverflow, should you need something else, search it around, and if you cant find it, then create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You should override your `onResume()` to check if the main activity is refreshed,so whenever you come back from setting activity to main activity .. it will get updated..

Comment: How can I do it ? I am so confused

Comment: @Elnoor -- '@Override
public void onResume()
    {  // After a pause OR at startup
    super.onResume();
    //Refresh your stuff here
    }'
*--or*
'@Override
public void onRestart() { 
    super.onRestart();
    //When BACK  is pressed, the activity on the stack is restarted
    //Do what you want on the refresh procedure here
}'

You could code what you want to do when the Activity is restarted (called again from the event 'back button pressed') inside onRestart(). 
i.e, if you want to do the same thing you do in onCreate(), paste the code in onRestart().

Answer (score 0):

In public void `onBackPressed()` method just write :

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with my problem. By the way that is the result: `void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)`